# How to define alternative font-family corresponding to font-size CSS

Tags: html, css, font-size

I declare font family in CSS:

```
body { 
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Verdana";
}
```

We all know it means that if the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font.

Now I want if the browser apply first font, it will apply font-size 12px; if the browser apply seccond font, it will apply font-size 10px,... and so on...

I wonder if we can declare like this

```
body { 
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Verdana";
    font-size: 12pt, 10pt;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555962/css-different-font-sizes-on-different-families

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `font-size-adjust`

Comment: Only supported by Firefox.