# Setting different line heights depending on the font

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I'd like to set different `line-height` for different fonts from a list fall-back fonts. For example:

```
body {
    font-family: "Small x-height font", "Larger x-height font", sans-serif;
}
```

When the preferred *Small x-height font* is used, I'd like to set `line-height` to 1.3. When *Larger x-height font* is used because the preferred font is not available, I'd like to set `line-height` to 1.5. When both fonts are not available and the sans-serif fallback is used, I'd like to set `line-height` to `normal`.

Is this possible using CSS 2.1 or CSS 3 without resorting to JavaScript?

**Rationale** The problem is that different fonts have different x-height (the height of lowercase letters such as x relative to the font size). To make text with larger x-height look good, it must be set with a larger line height. The x-height of the default fonts (sans-serif in the example above) is unknown and may differ drastically from the x-height of the font of our choice. So a line height that looks good with our font may look ugly when the font failed to load.

Comment: It's too bad you can't specify `line-height` in `@font-face`. If you head down the JS path, this jQuery plugin will allow you to set additional CSS properties when your font fails to load. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312323/how-to-know-if-a-font-font-face-has-already-been-loaded/12316349#12316349

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555962/css-different-font-sizes-on-different-families

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `font-size-adjust` property in CSS3 which addresses this problem. You can specify `font-size-adjust: 0.6` for your `body` and all fonts will be transparently scaled to have the x-height of 0.6em. This has the additional benefit that you can combine fonts with different original x-height on the same line and they will have roughly the same lowercase letter size without the need to adjust font sizes manually.

Only [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-size-adjust) implements `font-size-adjust` (as of November 2012). [WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=15257) does not.

See the [CSS3 Fonts](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop) specification for more information and [David Baron's post](http://dbaron.org/log/20080613-firefox3-css#font-size-adjust) for some examples.

Comment: The `font-size-adjust` property affects the size of the font, not line height. Moreover, its Firefox implementation is broken, as it uses wrong x-height information. So it’s a theoretically interesting answer to a question related to, but distinct from, the one asked.

Comment: The question was not about setting arbitrary line heights for different fonts. The intent was to match the line height to the font's x-height to make fallback fonts look just like the preferred font. So a working `font-size-adjust` property would be an ideal solution.

Comment: The question as asked was titled “Setting different line heights depending on the font”. And `font-size-adjust`, even if it were properly implemented, would not do that; see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-size-adjust-prop. I can see that you probably meant to ask about font size – but you didn’t.

Comment: Agree Q mixes height and size, but the goal of matching x-height is pretty clear.  The adjutsed size will also affect the line height, if it's in `ex` but not if unit-less / in percents: http://codepen.io/cben/pen/KwrmML.  And if one really wanted to increase line height without changing size, it shouldn't be hard to abuse `font-size-adjust` on invisible text...

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a way to do this in the exact way you are requesting.
However, I can tell you that if you are using a font service (eg Typekit), you may be able to style fallback fonts depending on whether the font has been loaded or not.

In Typekit's case, they add classes to the  element when the font is loading, loaded, or inactive. They also provide classes for the specific fonts/weights.

You can then provide specific styling depending on the situation.
Here's a rough example:

```
body {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 "typekit-font", "fallback-font";
}
.wf-inactive body {
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.8;
}
```

More information can be found in [their corresponding help article](http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/6787-font-events).

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that CSS3 has a property called font-size-adjust that was designed to address varying x-height of different fonts. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you cannot make the value of a property depend on the choice of a font. Basically, properties are independent of each other, with some exceptions that do not apply here.

Normally, fonts in a `font-family` list should be more or less similar in general characteristics. It’s not just a `line-height` matter. The choice of a font affects the page as a whole.

A different strategy is to use a downloadable font via `@font-face`. Then you can be reasonably sure that your font will be used, and you can set line height and other properties according to it.

Comment: There are some corner cases when an @font-face font cannot be loaded. Those include networking problems, external font service downtime, NoScript or another security tool blocking font loading, a saved page being viewed offline, etc. My question is concerned specifically with those cases.